# Navigation menu drop down tabs in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, tabs

I have a requirement create navigation menu tabs, each tab has child tab like drop-down menu. Whenever I click on the each tab corresponding content should display (same for sub tab also). I am facing css issue how to display correctly the sub tabs related to  menu and also need to display sub tab related content when i click on it.can anyone help me on this?

```js
$(document).ready(function(){


    $('ul#myNavUl li').on("click", (function(e) {   
   // Add selected class to clicked tab
   $(this).addClass('selected').siblings().removeClass('selected');
   
   // Determine selected li index in respect to parent ul
   var tabIndex = $(this).index();
   
   // Find article respective to selected tab
   var article = $(this).closest('.content').find('.articles').children().eq(tabIndex);
   
   // Add selected class to respective article
   article.addClass('selected').siblings().removeClass('selected');

    var parentH = $('ul#myNavUl li ul').parent().height();
    
    $('ul#myNavUl li ul').css('top', parentH);
    $('ul#myNavUl li ').hover(function(){
      $('ul', this).show();
    }, function(){
      $('ul', this).hide();
    });



}));

});
```

```css
body {
  background-color: #333;
  font-family: "Open Sans Condensed";
  margin: 0;

}

.content {
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 12px;
}

.article {
  display: none;
  margin: 100px auto 0;
  width: 1024px;
  padding: 8px 12px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  background-color: #f9f9f9;
}
.article.selected {
  display: block;
}
.article h2, .article p {
  color: #2a2a2a;
}

ul#myNavUl {
  list-style: none;
  text-align: center;
  color: #fff;
}

ul#myNavUl li {
  position: relative;
  width: 15%;
  margin: 0 4px;
  padding: 15px;
  float: left;
  background-color: #0077bb;
 
}
ul#myNavUl li:hover {
  background-color: #00aaee;
}
ul#myNavUl li.selected {
  background-color: #00aaee;
}
ul#myNavUl li.selected::after {
  position: absolute;
  display: block;
  width: 0;
  bottom: -15px;
  left: calc(50% - 15px);
  content: "";
  border-width: 15px 15px 0;
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: #00aaee transparent;
}

ul#myNavUl li a{
  text-decoration: none;
  color: white;
}

ul#myNavUl li ul{
      position:absolute;
        left:0;
      display:none;
    }
```

```html
<div class="content">
  <div class="tabs">
    <ul id="myNavUl">
      <li class="selected">Tab 1</li>
      <li><a href="#">Tab 2</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Tab 3</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Tab 4</a>
             <ul><!-- added drop-down items -->
                 <li><a href="#son-of-tab3" >drop-down 1</a></li> 
                 <li><a href="#son-of-tab3" >drop-down 2</a></li> 
                 <li><a href="#son-of-tab3" >drop-down 3</a></li> 
             </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div class="articles"> 
    <div class="article selected">
      <h2>Article 1</h2>
    </div>
    <div class="article">
      <h2>Article 2</h2>
    </div>
    <div class="article">
      <h2>Article 3</h2>
    </div>
    <div class="article">
      <h2>Article 4</h2>
    </div>
    <div class="article">
      <h2>Article 5</h2>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

I build for you a container with tabs and screens,
let me know if that what you looking for.

**html:**

```
<div id="tp--nav-bar">
  <ul id="nav-bar--list">
    <li class="controler">
      <a>home</a>
      <ul class="screen">
        <li><a>page</a></li>
        <li><a>page</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="controler">
      <a>about</a>
      <ul class="screen">
        <li><a>page</a></li>
        <li><a>page</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="controler">
      <a>gallery</a>
      <ul class="screen">
        <li><a>page</a></li>
        <li><a>page</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="controler">
      <a>contact</a>
      <ul class="screen">
        <li><a>page</a></li>
        <li><a>page</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

**scss:**

```
@mixin transition($ease, $s) {
  -webkit-transition: $ease $s;
     -moz-transition: $ease $s;
      -ms-transition: $ease $s;
      -o-transition:  $ease $s;
          transition: $ease $s;
}

@mixin translate($x, $y) {
  -webkit-transform: translate($x,$y);
     -moz-transform: translate($x,$y);
      -ms-transform: translate($x,$y);
       -o-transform: translate($x,$y);
          transform: translate($x,$y);
}


#nav-bar--list {
  font-family: 'Raleway', sans-serif;
  > li {
    cursor: pointer;
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
    float: left;
    width: 25%;
    height: 50px;
    line-height: 50px;
    text-align: center;
    background: #00aaee;
    color: #fff;
    overflow: hidden;
    a {
      display: block;
      width: 100%;
      height: 100%;
    }
  }
  > li.active {
    background: #007eb1;
    overflow: visible;
  }
  > li:hover {
    background: #007eb1;
  }
}

.screen {
  position: absolute;
  top: 100%;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  line-height: 40px;
  text-align: center;
  background: #00aaee;
  color: #fff;
  z-index: -1;
  opacity: 0;
  @include translate(0px, 50px);
  @include transition(cubic-bezier(0.4, 0.1, 0, 1.6), 0.45s);
     li:hover {
        background: #007eb1;
        a {
          color: #fff;
          text-decortion: none;
        }
     }
   }
.screen.active {
       z-index: 1;
       opacity: 1;
       @include translate(0px, 0px);
}
```

**jQuery:**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  tabPanel('#tp--nav-bar')
});


function tabPanel(element) {

  var container = $(element),
    controlers = container.find('.controler'),
    screens = container.find('.screen'),
    map = {};

  for (i = 0; i < controlers.length; i++) {

    var control = controlers[i],
      screen = screens[i],
      controler = 'controler-' + i,
      screener = 'screener-' + i;

    $(control).attr('id', controler);
    $(screen).attr('id', screener);

    map[controler] = screener;
  };

  controlers.click(function() {

    var controlerId = $(this).attr('id'),
      controlerClass = $(this).attr('class'),
      controlerClass = controlerClass.indexOf('active');

    if (controlerClass == -1) {

      controlers.removeClass('active');

      screens.removeClass('active');

      $('#' + map[controlerId]).addClass('active');

      $('#' + controlerId).addClass('active');

    }

  });

}
```

[My Fiddle](https://fiddle.jshell.net/zeevkatz/g1ntbngh/)

Comment: its not what I looking for,to the current tabs i need to child tabs , when i click on child tab it should also display like others.

Comment: You can take this and change it to yours. Change controler to 'li' and screen to ul inside the li parent.

Comment: You need a Fiddle with the changes?

Comment: there is a fiddle with the change https://fiddle.jshell.net/zeevkatz/g1ntbngh/23/

Comment: thank you but not found any content when i clicked on it and child tabs also not found.

Comment: Can you send me a sceenshot?

Comment: Hi! You still need help with that?

Answer (score 0):

I checked your code and looked in the console of the browser; it has one jQuery error like $ is not defined. I think you forget to add jQuery library; that's the way this error occurs. Add jQuery file or you can use jQuery cdn also like this.

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Add this line add before the `</body>` tag and then check if it works.

Comment: in the SO it will add it, so i have not added. but for my question its not answer.